# Random char in loop java

Tags: java

My problem is I dont know how I get the char in the loop. It has to be random and each char has to be in the loop for 10times.
Thanks

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        field();

    }

    public static void field() {

        final int WIDTH = 11;
        final int HEIGHT = 18;

        Random random = new Random();

        char l = 'L';
        char o = 'O';
        char u = 'U';


        for (int i = 0; i <= WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {

                if (i % 12 == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: *"each char has to be in the loop for 10times"* What does that mean? The loop is iterating *11 * 18 =* 198 times, so the `if` statement is true *ceil(198 / 12) =* 17 times, meaning that the `print` statement executes *198 - 17 =* 181 times.

Comment: The char (l,o and u) has to be in the loop for ten times. not every point in the loop has to be the char.

Comment: it has to be look like this:    .   .   .   .    .    .    .  O .  .  .  .  .L .   .   .    .   . U . . .  .  .  .. .... The char has to be there randomly ten times and everything else are points .

Comment: . . . . -O . . . -O . U .
. -O . . L . . U . .  L .
-O . R . L . . . . . . L 
. - O . . . L . .  . R . . . L . U - O . .  . . . . .

Comment: The *edit* the question and say that, i.e. *clarify* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to print out an 11x18 matrix with an exact number of randomly placed characters, you should build that up in memory first, e.g. in a 2D `char` array.

It's even easy to print, since the `print` methods can print a 1D `char` array directly.

The code would be something like this:

```
final int WIDTH = 11;
final int HEIGHT = 18;
final int CHAR_COUNT = 10;
final char[] CHARS = { 'L', 'O', 'U' };

// Create matrix filled with '.'
char[][] matrix = new char[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    Arrays.fill(matrix[i], '.');

// Randomly place CHAR_COUNT of each character from CHARS
Random random = new Random();
for (char ch : CHARS) {
    for (int i = 0, x, y; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) {
        do {
            x = random.nextInt(WIDTH);
            y = random.nextInt(HEIGHT);
        } while (matrix[y][x] != '.'); // Already filled, try again
        matrix[y][x] = ch;
    }
}

// Print matrix
for (char[] row : matrix)
    System.out.println(row);
```

*Sample Outputs*

```
....O....L.          .U......OL.          ......UO..L          ..OU.L..U.U
U.........O          ...........          L....L.....          ....O.....O
...........          ...........          .U....U....          ..........L
...........          ....L......          ..U..U...L.          ....O......
.....L.....          L.......LU.          ..L........          ...........
..L......O.          ...........          ..O.....U..          .........U.
....U......          ...O....U..          .........O.          ....LU.....
......O....          ...L..U....          .......O...          ........L..
..LU.......          L.O....O.UL          .......L..O          ..L....O..L
OL.U.......          U.........O          ...........          ......O....
.......L...          L....U.....          ...........          U..L...OU..
...U.....O.          ...........          ........U..          .........O.
........O..          .....O.L...          ........O..          U.......L..
..UL.......          ...........          ..L..L..OU.          ........L..
.....O..UU.          .......U...          ...........          .....L.O...
....O.U..U.          O..OUO...OL          .....O.....          ...........
.........L.          ...........          U....U..OLO          ......OU.U.
..L......LO          ....U......          L..........          ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadLocalRandom instead of Random, because is an improved Random class:

```
ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
```

Then, you can do something like this to get random chars:

```
System.out.println((char) random.nextInt(65, 97));
```

Notice how you can cast an integer to a char. The `random.nextInt(65, 97);` takes a range, in this case from 65 to 97, which is the ASCII range for the uppercase letters (A-Z).
And/or:

```
System.out.println((char) random.nextInt(97, 122));
```

Which will print the lowercase chars int he ASCII range 97 to 122 (a-z).

Comment: The char (l,o and u) has to be in the loop for ten times. not every point in the loop has to be the char.  it has to be look like this: . . . . . . . O . . . . .L . . . . . U . . . . . .. .... The char has to be there randomly ten times and everything else are points

Comment: . . . . -O . . . -O . U . . -O . . L . . U . . L . -O . R . L . . . . . . L . - O . . . L . . . R . . . L . U - O . . . . . . .